# Is it possible to call ReactDOM.render() when using JSX from vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Currently I'm learning ReactJS.
As I understand, code, written with JSX, has no different visibility scope with vanilla JS. But if I want to make some stuff on vanilla JS and only then call  ReactDOM.render() but still want to use JSX with React, is it possible and if yes - how?

Comment: Definitely possible. Here's a rather simple codepen example: http://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/yONZoW As you can see, we use JSX in our React components, but we call ReactDOM.render() in "normal" JS land.

Answer (score 1):

```
class RootComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
        return (
          <div >
            Hello, World.
          </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(RootComponent), 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Note that the render call has no JSX. This means you can split it from the main javascript file, and call it in any context, for example as inline javascript in a <script> tag:

main.js:

```
class RootComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
        return (
          <div >
            Hello, World.
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<script>
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(RootComponent), 
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.